# Нужен плагин авторизации через соцсети для angular

Tags: angularjs, auth

Для кордовы есть плагин, а для *ангуляра* так и не нашел.

В каком направлении искать?

Comment: https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth

Answer (score 1):

Для авторизации через соц.сети подойдет https://github.com/sahat/satellizer

Интеграция с:

Google, Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter, Instagram, GitHub, Bitbucket, Yahoo, Twitch, Microsoft (Windows Live) OAuth providers

Демо:

https://satellizer.herokuapp.com

Comment: Еще и вконтактик бы

Comment: ну так написано, OAuth providers, подключите VK